# What is the point of definnig Asp.net Intrinsic Objects In different places and what is the different betwen them?

Tags: asp.net, .net, web, page-lifecycle, infrastructure

I found out there are different classes that [Asp.net Intrinsic Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6w6xys5%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)(AIOs) are defined in them.
 `I want to know why? what is the logic and the reason behind this ?` 
You can find AIOs in these three different classes:
*I am not aware of any other classes in Asp.net*

1. [HttpContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext_members%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
2. [HttpApplication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
3. [Page Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

For example I am wondering that `HttpContext_instance.Request` and `HttpApplication_instance.Request` and `Page_instance.Request` are the same or Not?
And also what about the `Application object` in these three different places?And what about other AIOs?

Answer (score 0):

With most of the code base open sourced, you can read them to get a better image of the ASP.NET pipeline and see why such objects are often if not always the same.

An HTTP request coming from the network is parsed and embedded as an object and then passed down to every modules in the pipeline (HttpApplication) in a context (HttpContext). Then it meets a handler and hits a page. Thus you can also access the request object in the page.